# Issue with repeat delay in Python on Replit

Tags: python

I am trying to print a value to the console repeatedly. I print a value that increases by 1 each second. I have a function that spaces out the value so you can not see the previous time it was printed. My issue is that it skips past numbers (ex. from 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, etc.) Did I do something wrong or is it my slow computer?

(I am using Python on Replit. I am new to Python.)

```
def timeShow():
    print(timeValue)


timeValue = 1

import time
while True:
    timeShow()
    timeValue = timeValue + 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

CONSOLE:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dm7q7.png

Comment: Please share the link.

Comment: Nevermind, the error message talking about line 18 gives it away that you're not telling the truth about that being the code that produced it.

Comment: Edit the post and replace the picture with the error (as text)

Comment: That's not the full code. AttributeError means you can't perform that action on that object. This means you have a variable in your program named "time". Change that variable name to something else like "time1". You're clobbering the name "time"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please avoid posting images (or worse, links to images) of code or errors. Anything text-based (code and errors) should be posted as text directly in the question itself and formatted properly as a [mre]. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Sorry about image, I replaced it with written code

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a function named `time`. So you override the time import with your function. Rename the function and it will work.